# Consolidating and Pivoting Data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data source that describes transactions for sales formatted like this:

```
    Transaction |    Date   | Location |    UPC    | LineNumber
----------------+-----------+----------+-----------+------------
         123    | 7/2/2016  | Store A  | 123456789 |      1
         123    | 7/2/2016  | Store A  | 123965478 |      2
         124    | 7/2/2016  | Store A  | 123456789 |      1
         124    | 7/2/2016  | Store A  | 123459879 |      2
         124    | 7/2/2016  | Store A  | 123456789 |      3
         123    | 7/3/2016  | Store B  | 123456789 |      1
         123    | 7/3/2016  | Store B  | 958685458 |      2
```

In order to use this data in our reporting tools, I need to format this with the Transaction-Location as Unique and the UPC following on as columns based on line number:

```
Transaction |    Date   |  UPC 1    |   UPC 2   |  UPC 3
------------+-----------+-----------+----------
123-Store A | 7/2/2016  | 123456789 | 123965478 |   NULL
124-Store A | 7/2/2016  | 123456789 | 123459879 | 123456789
123-Store B | 7/3/2016  | 123456789 | 958685458 |   NULL
```

Any thoughts are appreciated

Comment: You should search for dynamic pivot. It has been asked and answered around here thousands of times.

Comment: Is the line number limited to 3?

Comment: Btw: You should avoid culture specific date-time formats. I assume you are talking about days in July, but this might be Feburary and March as well...

Comment: follow sean's comment...dynamic pivot's have been answered on this site repeatedly and you should find what you need.  You'll bit a bit more complicated as you'll be joining on a composite key...and a varchar one at that, this might not be a high performing query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard PIVOT will do the trick.  You just have to define your concatenated Transaction column in a CTE or nested Select before calling PIVOT.

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE ([Transaction] INT, Date DATE, Location VARCHAR(15), UPC INT, LineNumber INT)
INSERT INTO @Table ([Transaction], Date, Location, UPC, LineNumber)
VALUES
(123,'7/2/2016','Store A',123456789,1)
,(123,'7/2/2016','Store A',123965478,2)
,(124,'7/2/2016','Store A',123456789,1)
,(124,'7/2/2016','Store A',123459879,2)
,(124,'7/2/2016','Store A',123456789,3)
,(123,'7/3/2016','Store B',123456789,1)
,(123,'7/3/2016','Store B',958685458,2)

;WITH cteCombineTransLocation AS (
    SELECT
       CAST([Transaction] AS VARCHAR(50)) + '-' + Location as [Transaction]
       ,Date
       ,UPC
       ,LineNumber
    FROM
       @Table
)

SELECT
    [Transaction]
    ,[Date]
    ,[1] as UPC1
    ,[2] as UPC2
    ,[3] as UPC3
FROM
    cteCombineTransLocation
    PIVOT (
       MAX(UPC)
       FOR LineNumber IN ([1],[2],[3])
    ) p
```

If you want more UPC columns or if that number is dynamic then as the commenters pointed out you can use dynamic sql, but you will still need to prepare your concatenated field first.

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot.  I had the pivot but the cte was the missing link